# Java: Check if component is covered by JFrame.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jcomponent

In a complex Java component hierarchy, how can I find out if a certain component is covered by a KeyBinding that is added with `JFrame.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT` on a parent component? And why can it be a bad practice to add all KeyBindings with `JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`?

Comment: *Duplicate* keybindings are problematic with `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`, because the search order is unpredictable.

Comment: walk up the chain of parents and search their inputMaps